# Que es [::-1] en Python?

Tags: python, script

me gustaría saber en el siguiente código:

```
    import sys 

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    numero = sys.argv[1][::-1]
    longitud = len(numero)

    for i in range(longitud):
        print('{:0{}d}'.format(int(numero[i]) * 10 ** i, longitud))

else:
    print('Error, número de argumentos no válido')
    print('Ejemplo: python descomposicion.py [numero]')
```

Qué función cumple esto:

> [::-1]

y en qué situaciones se usa, gracias!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lo de `[::-1]` es un "truco" frecuentemente usado en python para obtener una lista o una cadena "del revés". Se basa en el operador *slice* (rodaja) cuya sintaxis general es:

```
iterable[inicio:fin:paso]
```

que permite extraer una serie de elementos del `iterable`, comenzando por el numerado como `inicio` y terminando por el numerado como `fin-1`, aumentando de `paso` en `paso`.

Si omites `inicio` se empezará en el primer elemento del iterable, si omites `fin` se terminará en el último elemento del iterable.

Si el `paso` es negativo, el iterable se recorre "hacia atrás", y en ese caso los valores por defecto cuando se omite `inicio` y `fin` se invierten.

Así pues `iterable[::-1]` devuelve los elementos del iterable, comenzando por el último y terminando por el primero, en orden inverso a como estaban.

Comment: Me quedo claro, gracias!