# ¿Como intercambiar las columnas de una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Hola a toda la comunidad de stack, hoy traigo un ejercicio sobre Matrices.

El ejercicio consiste en intercambiar las columnas de una matriz conformada por tuplas así:

```
    matriz=[[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],[(7,8,9),(11,12,13)]]
```

La matriz que entra por parámetro luce como la anterior y lo que debe hacer mi programa es intercambiar la posición de las comunas, a continuación pondré la matriz como debe quedar luego de ejecutado el programa.

```
    matriz=[[(3,2,1),(6,5,4)],[(9,8,7),(13,12,11)]]
```

El problema que tengo es que soy nuevo trabajando con matrices y desconozco de una estrategia que pueda ayudarme a solucionar este problema. **Considero importante resaltar que para la solución de este problema no puedo usar funciones especiales o métodos para matrices si existen, solo me debo valer de ciclos for o while**

conozco que puedo acceder a las columnas de la siguiente forma:

```
    filas=len(matriz)
    columnas=len(matriz[0])
    for i in range(0,filas):
        for j in range(0,columnas):
            print(matriz[i][j])
```

De la anterior forma tengo entendido que logro acceder a las columnas pero no se como intercambiarlas.

Si alguien me puede ayudar e informarme que me serviría para aprender a trabajar matrices lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

> En palabras simples una matriz es un conjunto ordenado en una estructura de filas y columnas

La forma más fácil de ordenar estructuras de este tipo es con una nueva matriz, recorrer la que tienes "desordenada" y luego ir agregando los datos según tus criterios de ordenamiento a la nueva matriz para así construir una nueva matriz totalmente ordenada.

```
matriz=[[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],[(7,8,9),(11,12,13)]]
matriz_invertida = []
for elemento in matriz:
    nueva_fila = []
    for fila in elemento:
        nueva_fila.append(tuple(reversed(fila)))
    matriz_invertida.append(nueva_fila)
print("Matriz original", matriz)
print("Matriz inversa", matriz_invertida)
```

Quizá la linea del código que te genere más ruido es la siguiente:

```
nueva_fila.append(tuple(reversed(fila)))
```

En este fragmento de código tomamos la fila y la invertimos con una función del propio lenguaje `reversed()`, posteriormente la convertimos a `tupla` para finalmente agregarla a una fila dentro de la nueva matriz.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente el código que has presentado va por buen camino, lo único que faltaría sería añadir `[::-1]` para obtener al revés las `tuplas` de interés [Que es [::-1] en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217819/que-es-1-en-python).

El código quedaría así:

```
matriz=[[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],[(7,8,9),(11,12,13)]]

n_filas = len(matriz)
n_columnas = len(matriz[0])
for i in range(n_filas):
    for j in range(n_columnas):
        matriz[i][j] = matriz[i][j][::-1] # se sobre escribe la matriz

print(*matriz, sep="\n")
"""
[(3, 2, 1), (6, 5, 4)]
[(9, 8, 7), (13, 12, 11)]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar slicing como propone @Hubert Ronald es la forma más simple y eficiente en mi opinión dado que las tuplas son inmutables, ahora si tampoco pudieras usar slicing, lo único que te queda es un tercer ciclo `for` usando un rango descendente y el constructor de `tuple`:

```
for row in matriz:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        tupla = row[i]
        row[i] = tuple(tupla[j] for j in range(len(tupla) - 1, -1, -1))
```

Si en vez de tuplas fueran listas podriamos hacer un intercambio in-place, pero como se ha comentado las tuplas son inmutables, por lo que tenemos que crear otras si o si.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta no publicar ejercicios ni tareas, va en contra del código de la comunidad, intenta hacer lo que te piden, y una vez te quedes "trabado" puedes publicar tu pregunta, con el respectivo código que intentaste.

Aparte todo depende del lenguaje que intentes utilizar para resolver el problema. Si lo quieres hacer en forma poco intuitiva en C por ejemplo....

solo tendrías que hacer

```
int* aux = matriz[x];
matriz[y] = matriz[x];
matriz[x] = aux;
```

siendo matriz un int* matriz[];

o en JS podrías hacer hacer

```
let aux = matriz[x];
matriz[y] = matriz[x];
matriz[x] = aux;
```

siendo matriz un array de arrays etc.
Pero tambien si te piden la forma lógica de hacerlo entonces sería cosa de copiar los elementos uno a uno.

¿Ves? No hay forma de poder ayudarte sin antes nos dijeras que nivel de programación tienes y/o que especificos te pidieron

Comment: Las etiquetas de la pregunta indican de forma clara que el lenguaje es Python

Comment: Además el OP si puede publicar ejercicios de tareas mientras vengan acompañados de lo que ha tratado, cosa que si notas si existe en la pregunta