# ¿Cómo determinar si una cadena es palíndroma? Es decir, si se lee igual de derecha a izquierda, que de izquierda a derecha

Tags: python, lista

Quiero comprobar si las palabras de una lista son palíndromos, es decir, si se lee igual de derecha a izquierda que de izquierda a derecha.

Se me ha ocurrido esto:

```
listT=['alba','aerea','alla','ana']
listF=['Roberto','Manuel','Jesus','Marea']
list1=listT + listF

for i in list1:
    for j in list1[i]:

        if id(j)==id(-j-1):
            print('Es un palíndromo')
        else:
            print('No es un palíndromo')
```

Pero da error en el segundo `for`:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

También se me había ocurrido de otra forma, utilizando dos índices, pero en Python no se puede hacer, por ejemplo:

```
lista1=['aerea','ana']
```

De forma que pueda determinar una letra de una lista, por ejemplo la 'a' de "aerea":

```
lista1[0[0]]
```

Y de esta forma podría hacer:

```
listT=['alba','aerea','alla','ana']
listF=['Roberto','Manuel','Jesus','Marea']
list1=listT + listF

for i in list1:
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):

        if list1[i[j]]==list1[i[-j-1]]:
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')
```

Esto tampoco se puede. ¿Cómo determinaría una letra de una palabra de una lista?

Comment: No sé que crees que hace la función [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#id), pero no funciona como piensas, seguro, ni tampoco tiene mucha utilidad para este caso. Ya te han dado una respuesta, si necesitas más explicaciones sólo tienes que indicarlo. Por cierto, un modo rápido para comprobar palíndromos: `palabra == palabra[::-1]`.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Esa es muy buena manera, nunca se me hubiera ocurrido.

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes mi intención era comprobar que las letras eran iguales, según he leído ' id ' da la identidad del objeto, por lo que mi intención era si el id es igual para i que para -i-1 entonces es un palindromo. A esto recurrí cuando ya no había manera de dar con la tecla. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @Jesús Pero con `id(i)` obtienes la _identidad_ de una variable llamada `i`, no tiene relación con la cadena. Aún con todo, sería posible que dos objetos tuvieran el mismo _valor_, pero que fueran diferentes objetos.

Comment: @ChemaCortes es cierto, esto tampoco lo sabía, poco a poco iré aprendiendo, muchas gracias de nuevo por su ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python podemos recorrer listas en ambos sentidos o incluso elemento a elemento, tal como hiciste en tu primer intento. Pero me parece que te liaste intentando usar dos bucles numéricos en vez de recorrerlo primero elemento a elemento y luego por índices, para evitar esos problemas, **es mejor nombrar las variables de manera que sepamos qué contienen con solo leerlas**, hacen que el código sea *mucho más fácil de seguir y no nos perdamos tanto*:

```
nombres = ['alba', 'aerea', 'alla', 'ana']

# Para cada palabra en la lista
for palabra in nombres:
    # Empezamos asumiendo que es un palíndromo
    es_palindromo = True
    # bucle de i = 0 hasta i menor que la longitud de la palabra
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        # En python los array se pueden recorrer desde el final también usando valores negativos, empezando en -1
        # Así que voy comparando la primera letra con la última, es decir palabra[0] y palabra[-1] y así hasta el final
        if palabra[i] != palabra[-(i+1)]:
            # Si las letras son diferentes, pongo es_palindromo a false e interrumpo la ejecución
            es_palindromo = False
            # No tiene sentido seguir comparando si ya sabemos que no es un palíndromo!
            break
    # Para terminar, si es palíndromo imprimo el mensaje positivo y si no el negativo
    if es_palindromo:
        print("La palabra ", palabra, " es un palíndromo")
    else:
        print("La palabra ", palabra, " no es un palíndromo")
```

Te he dejado en comentarios las explicaciones paso a paso, si hay algo que no entiendes no dudes en preguntar!!

Por cierto, aquí te has liado un poco:

```
# No funciona
list1[i[j]]
```

El acceso a listas múltiples se hace así: `list1[i][j]`, primero un índice y luego el otro

Comment: *"El acceso a arrays múltiples..."*. En Python no hay arrays de manera nativa, son listas...

Comment: Efectivamente, también podías haberlo editado que no me enfado! :) PD: De hecho al principio escribí listas, no sé por qué luego escribí arrays -.-'!

Comment: Hola @Benito-B , me has respondido a todo lo que quería, como tengo poca experiencia con Python, las ideas las tengo pero a la hora de ponerlas en código me cuesta. ¡Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda! Un saludo!

Answer (score 3):

Esta función evalua si una palabra es igual al revés y al derecho o no:

```
def es_igual(palabra):
    return all(palabra[idx] == palabra[-idx-1] for idx in range(len(palabra) // 2))
```

El método usado es recorrer la palabra como un arreglo de caracteres, comparando el primer con el último, el segundo contra el penúltimo y asi sucesivamente. Estas comparación la hacemos variando el indice desde cero hasta llegar a la mitad de la palabra:

```
for idx in range(len(palabra) // 2)
```

Por cada iteración, comparamos una letra del principio contra una letra del final:

```
palabra[idx] == palabra[-idx-1]
```

produciendo una lista de valores lógico.

Finalmente usamos la función `all` para determinar si todas las comparaciones arrojaron verdadero. Ese es el valor retornado.

Puedes usar esta función para evaluar la lista:

```
for palabra in lista:
    if es_igual(palabra):
        print(palabra, " es igual ")
```

**Demostración**

```
tests = ["", "A", "AB", "ABA", "MAMA", "OXO", "ROXO"]

for test in tests:
    print(test, es_igual(test))
```

produce

```
 True
A True
AB False
ABA True
MAMA False
OXO True
ROXO False
```

Comment: Hola @Candid Moe , esta función no la conocía, voy a leer detenidamente su método para comprender mejor, ¡muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

El error se debe a esta linea:

```
for j in range(len(list1[i])):
```

En la iteración que haces por encima (`for i in list1:`), `i` es cada elemento de `list1`, cuando intentas acceder a un indice así `list1[i]`, estás usando un string como indice de una lista. Algo así: `list1["string"]`, y esto evidentemente no es válido, y por eso se produce el error.

> ¿Cómo determinaría una letra de una palabra de una lista?

Si te refieres a acceder al indice de un string, desde el indice de una lista. La expresión `lista[m[n]]` no es válida, es como si m fuera una lista de números enteros y de casualidad el indice `n` de `m` existiera en `lista`. Además se tendría que encerrar entre paréntesis para indicar el orden de procedencia en la evaluación de la expresión.

La manera correcta sería `lista[m][n]`, debido a que `lista[m]` devuelve el elemento en la posición `m` de `lista` y después el indice `n` hace los mismo con `m` (que debería ser un iterable). Sin embargo, este aspecto no tiene relevancia al caso, si existen ciclos anidados.

Puedes comprobar si una palabra es la misma de derecha a izquierda que de izquierda a derecha, iterando por los indices de una cadena en direcciones contrarias.

```
def es_palindromo(palabra):
    for i,j in zip(range(len(palabra)),range(len(palabra) - 1,-1,-1)):
        if palabra[i] != palabra[j]:
            return False
        
        return True
```

Este ejemplo itera por los indices del string `palabra` hacia la derecha (`i`) y hacia la izquierda (`j`), si la posición `i` de la cadena es diferente a la de `j` se retorna `False`, si muere el ciclo se va a retornar `True`.

Entonces se me ocurre que puedes escribir una función de este tipo y usarla para verificar que cada palabra de una lista es un palíndromo o no.

```
for item in lista:
    if es_palindromo(item):
        #...
    else:
        #...
```

También en vez de retornar un valor puedes imprimir mensajes por pantalla. Es solo un ejemplo, ya verás como adaptarlo a tu caso.

### Edit:

Puedes hacer uso de un `slice` como indice de una cadena para invertirla, de esta manera si la comparación de la cadena inversa es igual a la cadena original, es palíndromo.

```
if cadena == cadena[::-1]:
    #...
```

Donde:

- `:`: Los primeros dos puntos sin operando izquierdo ni derecho, indican que se selecciona desde el inicio hasta el final de la cadena.
- `:-1`: El paso negativo indica que se va a leer la cadena al reverso.

Tienes una explicación más completa en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217819/que-es-1-en-python).

Comment: Hola @Gabitohh , voy a practicar con su método, ya que no conocía ' def ', ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!