# Cambio de orden de palabras en python

Tags: python

Deseo realizar lo siguiente, a traves de un input que se ingrese por consola una cadena de caracteres, ejempl(Hola como estas?) y que me retorne las mismas palabras, pero en distinto orden, es decir (estas como Hola?).

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo pero no me sirve porque esto me cambia el orden letra por letra

```
cadena=input("Ingrese la palabra: ")
    for i in range(len(cadena) -1, -1, -1):
        print(cadena[i], end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir la cadena a lista, por medio de un criterio de división. En este caso serían los espacios.

Una vez que tienes la lista, puedes invertirla de cualquier forma existente. La [más pitónica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217825/80870) es usando `iterable[::-1]`, pero puedes usar un ciclo `for` u otra cosa si quieres

El algoritmo ejecutado en la consola:

```
>>> cad = "Hola como estas?"
>>> final = ''
>>> if(cad[-1] in ['.', '!', '?']): # comprobar si hay un signo de puntuación final
...     final = cad[-1] # El ultimo elemento de la cadena
...     cad = cad[:-1] # Todos los elementos, excepto el último
>>> cad
'Hola como estas' # efectivamente cortó el ultimo caracter.
>>> palabras = cad.split(' ') # Divide la cadena en una lista de palabras
>>> palabras
['Hola', 'como', 'estas']
>>> palabras_inv = palabras[::-1] # Se hace la inversión
>>> palabras_inv
['estas', 'como', 'Hola']
>>> cad_inv = ' '.join(palabras_inv) + final # Se convierte en cadena y se añade el final
>>> cad_inv
'estas como Hola?'
```

Comment: Perfecto, quedo muy bien explicado, muchas gracias!

Comment: Pero en dado caso que el último caracter no sea un punto, una coma o un signo, como podría hacerlo para que aplique para cualquier caracter? Ya sea una letra, signo de puntuación, o un espacio en blanco?

Comment: @AlejandroPereira si es siempre el último caracter, entonces quita el `if` (obviamente acomodando la indentación) y aplicará siempre. Si es cualquier caracter que no sea una letra, entonces el `if` lo cambias a `if not cad[-1].isalpha():` Doc [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias mi estimado!